# How to enumerate smartcard logon attempts in Windows?

Tags: authentication, windows-server

I need to provide my users with feedback when they log on at their workstations. This feedback needs to include:

- Date/time and workstation id of last successful login
- Number of unsuccessful login attempts since last successful login

The environment is Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 with Active Directory, and the use of smartcards is enforced for interactive login. We are using .NET compatible smartcards.

We have successfully implemented the feedback on the date/time of last successful login, but are having difficulties to implement the other feedback. The question is, what options do we have for implementation of this feedback?

Comment: I assume Active Directory?

Comment: @DKNUCKLES Yes - edited to clarify this point.